# Get the value from the database based on time

Tags: vb.net

I have a table consist of subject name, start time, end time and its day. I have a question, is it possible to automatically get the value of a row based on specific time and day?

Example

current time = 12:00 PM
current day = Wednesday

In the table:
PHP 9:00 AM - 1:00 PM (Wed)
VB 2:00 PM - 5:00 PM (Wed)

Output
Value will be PHP

Comment: Exact command depends on the Database server you are using. Sql has `GETDATE()`, Oracle has `SYSDATE`, both of which return the current date/time as reported on the server. If you want any more help, we will need to see the code you are running

Answer (score 0):

The SQL would be something like:

```
SELECT SubjectName
FROM Table
WHERE @Time >= StartTime
  AND @Time <= EndTime
  AND @Day = Day
```

where @Time is a parameter that is the time you're checking for, and @Day is the day.

NB the SQL won't be exact as I'm typing from memory, but should probably be enough to get you close.